# How to Sort Data in Firebase RealTime Database based on Future Date/Time

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am creating an app and a main feature of the app is that a user will be able to plan trips in the future and the app will notify him when to start navigating there. I want to store and sort upcoming trips based on **date and time** (the closest one on the current date being first).

I found some answers in StackOverflow about the date issue but all of the answers were about getting the current time from the system using `ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` (and storing it using timestamp in the Firebase Realtime Database).

This only works for storing the current date and time. I am interested to get the timestamp for future dates.

The trips are currently stored by the order they are added on my database as you can see on the image below:
[image]

I currently write data for the trip in the database as a Trip object, like this:

```
    //Store date,time and destination on a new Trip.
    datePassed = dateText.getText().toString();
    timePassed = timeText.getText().toString();

    trip = new Trip(destinationPassed, datePassed, timePassed);

    //Get uId of the Firebase User.
    String uId = currentFirebaseUser.getUid();

    //Create a unique Hash Key for the Trip. (Used to Distinguish trips)
    String tripId = Integer.toString(trip.getTripId(destinationPassed, datePassed, timePassed));

    //Store the trip on Firebase RealTime Database.
    DatabaseReference childReff = dbRef.child(uId).child("trips").child(tripId);
    childReff.setValue(trip);
```

and I retrieve the data like this:

```
    //Get uId of the user
    final String uId = currentFirebaseUser.getUid();


    dbRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            for (DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.child(uId).child("trips").getChildren()) {

                //Here I access each child separately (destination, date, time)
                date = child.child("date").getValue().toString();
                destination = child.child("destination").getValue().toString();
                time = child.child("time").getValue().toString();
```

My question is how can I achieve to store and trips in ascending order (the closest one on the current date being first) for trips that are set in the future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I figured out the answer. I will post what I did in case somebody has the same question in the future.

I created a method that transforms String dates into Long(Milliseconds). (This is what the firebase database uses for time and date.)

```
   public Long toMilli(String dateIn) throws ParseException {
    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");
    Date date = (Date) formatter.parse(dateIn);
    long output = date.getTime() / 1000L;
    String str = Long.toString(output);
    long timestamp = Long.parseLong(str) * 1000;
    return timestamp;
    }
```

I transform the date by calling the method:

```
//Store date,time and destination on a new Trip.
    datePassed = dateText.getText().toString();
    timePassed = timeText.getText().toString();

    String dateSelected = dateText.getText().toString() + " " + timeText.getText().toString();
    Long timestamp = toMilli(dateSelected);
```

I created a new construction for Trip and store the new timestamp(Long) there and stored the Trip in the database.

```
    public Trip(String destination, Long timestamp) {
    this.destination = destination;
    this.timestamp = timestamp;
}
```

To read the data from the firebase:

```
    //Get uId of the user
    final String uId = currentFirebaseUser.getUid();


    dbRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            for (DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.child(uId).child("trips").getChildren()) {
                String destination = child.child("destination").getValue().toString();
                Long timestamp = child.child("timestamp").getValue(Long.class);
```

The next step is to transform Long to String, I created a new method for that.

```
    public String convertTime(long time){
    Date date = new Date(time);
    Format format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");
    return format.format(date);
}
```

And finally call the method:

```
String time=convertTime(timeLong);
```

Before reading the data I created a new ArrayList
I then create a new object - Trip in my case and passed in the values.
Everytime I was reading a child trip - with the for loop I was adding it to the list.

At the end I sorted the list before displaying it to the user. You have to override CompareTo in order for this to work.